# Enable services propedeutical to activate network

Tags: windows-vista

I've got a PC with Windows Vista.
Due to a malaware I had to disable all services by doing:

Run->msconfig

In the services tab I then clicked on disable all and rebooted.
I solved the problem with the malaware but unfortunately I am able no more to to connect using my provider's pen drive with prepaid time (and no: I still have time:-))

Since the only thing I did was to disable all services, can someone tell me which are the services to enable again?

I just could not enable all because the malaware had not been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

If you open `msconfig` you will notice the disable date is reported too. Sort the services by date, and enable everything that isn't:

[image: System Configuration]

Comment: sorry, I forgot to reply. You have been very helpful. I just didnt' care about this option